# Create a 3D array from dataframe with different lenghts of rows

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

Using only the time, lon and lat columns, what I want is to create a 3D array with shape (2,16,2), where the first dimension is the time (in this case, there are 2 times: 2 or 3), the second is the total number of rows representing each pair of lat-lon coordinates, and the last dimension is the lat-lon pair
.

The 3d array should be something like this:

```
    array([[[ 85.573875, -50.856796],
    [ 22.516417, -64.196556],
    [  4.072308, -48.226948],
    [ 24.439985, -47.150661],
    [129.924103, -50.699009],
    [296.879486, -20.473812],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan]],

   [[282.733734, -58.982613],
    [346.649414, -49.212891],
    [105.564247, -59.02515 ],
    [ 77.098854, -61.031345],
    [ 93.66552 , -52.018295],
    [ 26.899933, -65.549835],
    [  8.558081, -48.222881],
    [ 28.211027, -50.188721],
    [137.030777, -51.931877],
    [295.907715, -20.918041],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan],
    [       nan,        nan]]])
```

You can notice from the dataframe that for each time value (2 and 3) there are different amounts of data/rows. So the idea is to, right before the first time changes from 2 to 3, the remaining empty values ​​have to be filled with NaN, and then moves to the second time (time=3). The purpose of the NaN values ​​is to maintain the shape of the array (2,16,2).

I don't know if I made myself clear. Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

---

EDIT:
This is what I was doing so far:

Assuming that df is the name of the dataframe that I showed above:

```
array1 = np.zeros((1,16,2)) #creates an empty array
for i in range(0,16):
    if (df.iloc[i,1]==2): #selects only the data with time=2
        array1[:,i,:] = [df.iloc[i,2],df.iloc[i,3]]
    else:
        array1[:,i,:] = [np.nan,np.nan] #fills the rest with NaN values

array2 = np.zeros((1,16,2))
for i in range(0,16): 
    if (df.iloc[i,1]==3): #selects only the data with time=3
        array2[:,i,:] = [df.iloc[i,2],df.iloc[i,3]]
    else:
        array2[:,i,:] = [np.nan,np.nan] #fills the rest with NaN values

array2 = np.roll(array2,10,axis=1) #adjusts the position of the nan values

merged_arrays = np.vstack((array1,array2)) #the required final array, with shape (2,16,2)
```

I would like you to help me develop a more direct and clear method to create this 3D array from the dataframe.

Comment: What is your question? You've not described any problem, only what your code currently does. What would you _like_ it to do?

Comment: What I want is to create a 3D array with shape (2,16,2) from the dataframe, using the time, lat and lon columns. In this array, the first dimension is the time (2 or 3), the second is the total number of rows representing each pair of lat-lon coordinates, and the last dimension is the lat-lon pair. The final result should look like the one I showed.

Comment: So the result you've posted it not a result of code, but a hand-generated output? SO is a place to get help debugging existing code, and not as a code-writing service. Please show what you've attempted so far, so that we can help :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post showing what I've done so far. Thanks!

Comment: pandas can leverage the xarray python module to create 3D dataframes:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html